# Insert picture via CSS table

Tags: html, css

I am quite new to web development, and recently, I have been wondering if it is possible to insert an image into a CSS table. The reason I would want to do this, is that, I do not want an user to right click on a picture and see "Save image as" or "View image". Not that my images are sensitive or copyrighted - it just does not look elegant.

For example, when I look at 
    www.1and1.co.uk 
I have these three images in the middle: "Domains", "One and One Hosting" and "My business site". However, when any of these images are right clicked, I do not see "save image" or "view image". Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Sorry if the question is not of high intellectual content :(

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What are you referring to as "CSS table"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the css attribute `background-image`:

```
#my_element {
  background-image:url(/images/my_image.jpg);
}
```

Comment: If I use "background-image:url" then when I right click, I see "view background image". Any way to avoid this? I was hoping if I create a table in CSS and insert an image into the table (?) would solve the problem? But, I am not sure.

Comment: Nope. Well, not without painfully ugly hacks. You would have to use positioning and z-indexing to overlay some invisible element. I can't think any reason in the world you would want to do this, as that is just how browsers function.

Comment: Thanks..I see what you mean...I am new to it, so, I didnt know that. Only when I looked at 1and1.co.uk I was surprised that I could not view the image, although I could see the image link in firebug.

Comment: @James W whatever method and you use, from the moment that images are downloaded in user's machine, he can save them.

Comment: Thanks tybro and Sotiris. Your comments were really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Simply you can achieve this through the css `background-image` property.